# Speed Up Retrieving View Data?

Tags: titanium, dominotogo

The database I am trying to pull data from has approximately 50,000 documents. Currently it takes around 90 seconds for an iOS or Android device to query and display the data to the mobile device in a view. My code is posted below. Is there something I could be doing differently to speed this up? Thanks for any tips.

```
function updateAllPoliciesTable() {
    try {
        var db = Alloy.Globals.dbPolicyInquiry;
        var view = db.getView("AllRecordsByInsured");
        var vec = view.getAllEntriesBySQL("Agent like ? OR MasterAgent like ?", [Ti.App.agentNumber, Ti.App.agentNumber], true);

        var ve = vec.getFirstEntry();
        var data = [];
        while (ve) {
            var unid = ve.getColumnValue("id");
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                unid : unid,
                height: '45dp',
                rowData: ve.getColumnValue("Insured") + "  " + ve.getColumnValue("PolicyNumber")
            });

            var viewLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                color : '#333',
                font : {
                    fontSize : '16dp'
                },
                text: toTitleCase(ve.getColumnValue("Insured")) + "  " + ve.getColumnValue("PolicyNumber"),
                left: '10dp'
            });

            row.add(viewLabel);
            data.push(row);
            ve = vec.getNextEntry();
        }

        //Ti.API.log("# of policies= " + data.length);

        if(data.length == 0) {
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                title : "No policies found"
            });
            data.push(row);
        }

        $.AllPoliciesTable.setData(data);
        Alloy.Globals.refreshAllPolicies = false;
        Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
    } catch (e) {
        DTG.exception("updateAllPoliciesTable -> ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you time how long it takes the query to return? Is the hangup in the UI or in the DB? Do you have to use a `like` query?

Comment: Josiah has a good point.  Is it the retrieval of the data or the rendering of the data to the screen that is slow?  You may need to create an index as suggested by others or you might need to optimize the row code.  Look into className of the TableViewRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on the appropriate table, that should speed up things. 
The SQLite table for your view should be named "view_AllRecordsByInsured". 
Create an index for that table, check SQLite documentation about "CREATE INDEX" for more details.

To execute the appropriate SQL, you could use the DTGDatabase class like

```
var sqldb = new DTGDatabase(Alloy.Globals.dbPolicyInquiry.localdbname);
sqldb.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON view_AllRecordsByInsured (Agent,MasterAgent)")
```

If that does give enough speed, look at full text search for SQLite dbs. 
Here is some example code regarding full text indexes to give you a starting point:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ft_view__mobile_companies_ USING fts4(id, customername, customercity)
INSERT INTO ft_view__mobile_companies_(id, customername, customercity) SELECT id, customername, customercity FROM view__mobile_companies_
```

To query the index you need to execute SQL with the MATCH operator (see SQLite documentation). In one app I have well over 100.000 datasets synchronized from a Domino view, and searching using a fulltext search in SQLite works instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unlike big database engines, the SQLite database engine is more limited, and so are the devices that it's run on.

What I would try to do is check the query that pulls the data - are you using indexes in your table? do you use them to query? is there unnecessary joins or pulls?

I you fail to tweet the query you should maybe consider checking out a mobile noSQL solution - I know there are some on the appcelerator marketplace - check if it suits your needs and if it speeds up things.